# Search Service Application using existing databases

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-search

I have an existing search service application with crawled data and corrupted search index. I tried to recreate search topology with clone but didn't work.  How can I create a new search service application using the existing SSA databases so that I don't have to re-crawl. Current crawl took me 12 days so that don't want to lose that data.

Comment: I don't know if that is possible but how will you build the index if you don't run a crawl? Doing a crawl will do both things.